# read.csv in R returns nothing

Tags: r, macos, csv, read.csv

I'm brand new to R and having a basic issue. I need to import a file "testfile.csv" and store it in a variable called "data".

I have my working directory set correctly (I think), but my file only contains a single column of values. When I run the following code, nothing happens but I don't get an error either...

```
setwd("/Users/myname/Desktop")
data <- read.csv(file = "testfile.csv",header = TRUE,",quote = "" ,fill = TRUE)
summary(data)
```

I'm working on OSX if that makes a difference.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this the exact copy of command? If yes, you put the extra `"`, try this: `data <- read.csv(file = "testfile.csv",header = TRUE,quote="",fill = TRUE)`.

Comment: Thank you! Just made a dumb mistake, my bad.

Comment: Btw, you can use `getwd()` to check the working directory.